# JBoss CLI special characters in property name

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, keycloak

I have a JBoss CLI script which adds some properties to the configuration file of a keycloak server.

Some of the properties I want to add contain dots e.g.  `name=max.block.ms, value=5000`. When I check the config file I see this `<property name="max" value="{&quot;block&quot; => {&quot;ms&quot; => 5000}}"/>`

I only found this [official guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/html-single/management_cli_guide/index#braces) which explains how to handle special characters in the value, but this doesn't work for the name.

EDIT:
This is the line from my script

```
/subsystem=keycloak-server/spi=eventsListener/provider=kafka:write-attribute(name=properties.max.block.ms,value=5000)
```

Comment: Please show your script.

Comment: Added the line in question from my script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command may be a workaround:

```
/subsystem=keycloak-server/spi=eventsListener/provider=kafka:map-put(name=properties,key=max.block.ms,value=5000)
```